# Webserver doesn't open files include %

Tags: linux, apache, filesystems, webserver, system-administration

I have a webserver (linux) and it looks like that all files include `%` they are not displayed
like

> image%2filename.jpg

I have to rename all those thousand files and remove that `%2` but as long as they are too many is there any option on server that will allow me to support it?

Answer (score 0):

%20 is the HTML character for a space. So you likely want your filenames to have a space in them like "image filename.jpg" and then if you are loading that image on an HTML page you could either use a real space character or %20 in the filename such as  or .